# Extended arrays with 12 parameters

Tags: macros, matrices

I have a document to type where I need to write a lot of extended arrays and I want to create a function that does this nicely but unfortunately both the ´\def´ and ´\newcommand´ commands only allow 9 parameters, and I have 12. Can anyone help me? help?

```
(A|b)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        2&1&-2&0\\
        -1&3&1&0\\
        2&1&1&z
        \end{array}\right)
```

Comment: i would  just have one argument and use `\foo{2&1&-2&0\\-1&3&1&0\\2&1&1&z}` which seems clearer than `\foo{2}{1}{-2}{0}{-1}{3}{1}{0}{2}{1}{z}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that something like

```
\extarray{2}{1}{-2}{0}{-1}{3}{1}{0}{2}{1}{1}{z}
```

is maintainable.

Here's my proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{extarray}[1][3]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}%
}{\end{array}\right)}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{extarray}[1] A & b \end{extarray} =
\begin{extarray}
  2 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 -1 & 3 &  1 & 0 \\
  2 & 1 &  1 & z
\end{extarray}
\]

\[
\begin{extarray}[1] A & b \end{extarray} =
\begin{extarray}[4]
 3 &  2 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 4 & -1 & 3 &  1 & 0 \\
 5 &  2 & 1 &  1 & z \\
 0 &  0 & 0 &  1 & z
\end{extarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note the uniformity in spacing and the possibility to have whatever number of columns you wish.

[image]

With an “inline” syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\extarray}{O{3}m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \left(\begin{array}{@{} *{#1}{c} | c @{}}
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_seq \__zaragosa_row:n
  \end{array}\right)
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zaragosa_row:n { \clist_use:nn { #1 } { & } \\ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\extarray[1]{A,b}=
\extarray{2,1,-2,0 ; -1,3, 1,0 ; 2,1, 1,z}
\]

\[
\extarray[1]{A,b}=
\extarray[4]{
  3, 2,1,-2,0 ; 
  4,-1,3, 1,0 ;
  5, 2,1, 1,z ;
  0, 0,0, 1,z
}
\]

\end{document}
```

For the “augmented matrix” notation (A|b) you may want to define

```
\newcommand{\augm}[2]{\begin{extarray}[1] #1 & #2 \end{extarray}}
```

for the first implementation and

```
\newcommand{\augm}[2]{\extarray[1]{#1,#2}}
```

for the `expl3` one to be used as `\augm{A}{b}` in either case.

Comment: I loved this answer! Thank you very much

Comment: @Zaragosa I added a different implementation.

Comment: (+1) Thank you, seriously this post will be very helpful for me!

Answer (score 3):

I may humbly suggest using `spalign` package where you can align center `c`, left `l`, and right `r`, and get the result that you got.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{spalign}


\begin{document}
\[(A\mid b)=\spalignaugmatn[c]{1}{2 1 -2 0; -1 3 1 0; 2 1 1 z}\]
\[(A\mid b)=\spalignaugmatn[l]{1}{2 1 -2 0; -1 3 1 0; 2 1 1 z}\]
\[(A\mid b)=\spalignaugmatn[r]{1}{2 1 -2 0; -1 3 1 0; 2 1 1 z}\]

\[(A\mid b)=\spalignaugmatn[r]{1}{3 2 1 -2 0; 4 -1 3 1 0; 5 2 1 1 z; 0 0 0 1 z
}\]
\[(A\mid b)=\spalignaugmatn[l]{1}{3 2 1 -2 0; 4 -1 3 1 0; 5 2 1 1 z; 0 0 0 1 z
}\]
\[(A\mid b)=\spalignaugmatn[c]{1}{3 2 1 -2 0; 4 -1 3 1 0; 5 2 1 1 z; 0 0 0 1 z
}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that could be done!!! Thank you very much for your great answer!

Comment: @Zaragosa This package is very useful when you want to build segmented matrices. I am happy that you liked it. Be careful to put a space between a digit or letter as shown in my example.